# Looking for synonym 'look into heart' or 'reexamine thoughts'

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for synonyms for 'reexamine thoughts'. I want to use the synonym in a context where I want to say 'think about myself or karmas before going to bed'.

Answer (score 3):

> Reminisce
>
> - to recall past experiences, events, etc.; indulge in reminiscence.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reminisce?s=t

> Reflect
>
> - to think, ponder, or meditate: to reflect on one's virtues and faults.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reflect?s=t

Answer (score 0):

Pondering and contemplating spring to mind.

I will add definitions when I'm at my computer.